# 'withRouter' is not exported from 'react-router-dom'

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

```
Failed to compile. Attempted import error: 'withRouter' is not exported from 'react-router-dom'.
```

My code like, also I have installed `react-router-dom` an react-route and I have respin the app 10 time now

```
import React from 'react';
import {withRouter} from 'react-router-dom';

import './menu-item.scss';

const MenuItem = ({ title, imageUrl, size, history }) => (
  <div className={`${size} menu-item`}>
    <div
      className='background-image'
      style={{
        backgroundImage: `url(${imageUrl})`,
      }}
    />
    <div className='content'>
      <h1 className='title'>{title.toUpperCase()}</h1>
      <span className='subtitle'>SHOP NOW</span>
    </div>
  </div>
);

export default withRouter(MenuItem);
```

Comment: great shout, and similar to Switch ( will through the same error ) here is the downgrade command, just make sure you are in the right directory 
npm install react-router-dom@5.0.0

Answer (score 14):

If you accidentally installed `react-router-dom` v6 then the `withRouter` HOC no longer exists. Either revert back to v5 (*run `npm install -s react-router-dom@5`*), or roll your own custom `withRouter` HOC to inject the props you need or convert the components to function components and use the React hooks.

## Create custom `withRouter` Higher Order Component

From the FAQ: [What happened to withRouter I need it](https://reactrouter.com/en/6.4.0/start/faq#what-happened-to-withrouter-i-need-it)

> ```
> import {
>   useLocation,
>   useNavigate,
>   useParams,
> } from "react-router-dom";
>
> function withRouter(Component) {
>   function ComponentWithRouterProp(props) {
>     let location = useLocation();
>     let navigate = useNavigate();
>     let params = useParams();
>     return (
>       <Component
>         {...props}
>         router={{ location, navigate, params }}
>       />
>     );
>   }
>
>   return ComponentWithRouterProp;
> }
> ```

## Convert to function component

There is now also no longer a `history` object to use, it was replaced by a `navigate` function accessed via the `useNavigate` hook. It's not clear where `history` was being used previously, but if you need to imperatively navigate the following is how you access the navigation. If staying with v6 then the following is how to access the `navigate` function.

```
import React from 'react';
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';

import './menu-item.scss';

const MenuItem = ({ title, imageUrl, size }) => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  // navigate("/targetPath")

  return (
    <div className={`${size} menu-item`}>
      <div
        className='background-image'
        style={{
          backgroundImage: `url(${imageUrl})`,
        }}
      />
      <div className='content'>
        <h1 className='title'>{title.toUpperCase()}</h1>
        <span className='subtitle'>SHOP NOW</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
};

export default MenuItem;
```

Answer (score 2):

thanks to  Drew Reese -great shout-, and similar to Switch ( will throw the same error ) here is the downgrade command, just make sure you are in the right directory

```
npm install react-router-dom@5.0.0
```

Comment: FYI, it looks like 5.3.0 is the latest v5.x version as of today, but v5.2.1 has been stable for a long time. It seems to run without issue in the codesandboxes I've been testing in.

Answer (score 2):

You can use useLocation hook and destructure 'pathname' property from it to make the navigated link in the onClick() function dynamic.

Here's a sample of the code that worked for me:

```
  import React from "react";
  import { useLocation, useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
  import "./menu-item.styles.scss";

  const MenuItem = ({ title, imageUrl, size, linkUrl, match }) => {
    let navigate = useNavigate();
    // destructured "pathname" property from useLocation()
    let { pathname } = useLocation();
    // consoloe.log(pathname)
    return (
      <div className={`${size} menu-item`} onClick={() => navigate(`${pathname}${linkUrl}`)}>
        <div
          className="background-image"
          style={{
            backgroundImage: `url(${imageUrl})`,
          }}
        />
        <div className="content">
          <h1 className="title">{title.toUpperCase()}</h1>
          <span className="subtitle">SHOP NOW</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  };

  export default MenuItem;
```

Answer (score 1):

in **menu-item.component.jsx** you can use the **useNavigate** just like this one

```
import React from "react";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

import "./menu-item.styles.scss";

const MenuItem = ({ title, imageUrl, size, history, linkUrl, match }) => {
  let navigate = useNavigate();
  return (
    <div className={`${size} menu-item`} onClick={() => navigate(`${linkUrl}`)}>
      <div
        className="background-image"
        style={{
          backgroundImage: `url(${imageUrl})`,
        }}
      ></div>

      <div className="content">
        <h1 className="title">{title.toUpperCase()}</h1>
        <span className="subtitle">SHOP NOW</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default MenuItem;
```

Also, in **App.js** you should import **Routes** and **Route** from **react-router-dom** and make your code like this:

```
import React from "react";
import { Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";

import "./App.css";
import HomePage from "./pages/homepage/homepage.component";

const HatsPage = () => (
  <div>
    <h1>Hats page</h1>
  </div>
);

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Routes>
        <Route exact path="/" element={<HomePage />} />
        <Route path="/hats" element={<HatsPage />} />
      </Routes>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

As for me, this works.

Answer (score 0):

try this it worked for me

```
import React from "react";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

import "./menu-item.styles.scss";

const MenuItem = ({ title, imageUrl, size, history, linkUrl, match }) => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  return (
    <div className={`${size} menu-item`} onClick={() => navigate(`hats`)}>
      <div
        className="background-image"
        style={{
          backgroundImage: `url(${imageUrl})`,
        }}
      ></div>

      <div className="content">
        <h1 className="title">{title.toUpperCase()}</h1>
        <span className="subtitle">SHOP NOW</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default MenuItem;
```